# Remove all keys except one from JSONObject

Tags: java, json, java-8

I have a JSONObject (org.json) like this:

```
{
    "a": "a",
    "b": "a",
    "c": "a",
    "d": "a",
    "e": "a",
    "f": "a",
    "g": "a",
    ...
}
```

I would like to remove all the keys except `a`. Is there an elegant way to do this other than my naive approach?

```
Iterator<String> keys = jsonObject.keys();
while (keys.hasNext()) {
    if (!keys.next().equals("a")) {
        keys.remove();
    }
}
```

Expected output:

```
{"a": "a"}
```

Comment: Introduce a List before iterating, and add elements to it where `key != "a"`. And then iterate over this list, and remove keys by using jsonObject.remove(key)

Comment: I only need `a`, why would I store everything other than `a`?

Comment: Are you appose to using gson? Are you trying to just use org.json.JSONObject?

Comment: @Jason, I can use `org.json.JSONObject` only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you consider creating a new object with the required key?

```
jsonObject = new JSONObject().put("a", jsonObject.get("a"));
```

Answer (score 5):

I believe a simpler way to do that would be using `removeIf` as

```
jsonObject.keySet().removeIf(k -> !k.equals("a"));
```

Answer (score 3):

Without using Gson, this is one way that you could reduce the line count but i'm not a huge fan of using ArrayList to create a copy of the keys to prevent a ConcurrentModificationException. Honestly, what you have isn't bad.

```java
          new ArrayList<>(object.keySet())
                    .stream()
                    .filter(key -> !key.equals("a"))
                    .forEach(object::remove);
```

I would even declare the List and make it 2 lines because of that horrid new ArrayList call.

```java
            List<String> keysForRemoval = object.keySet()
                    .stream()
                    .filter(key -> !key.equals("a"))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

            keysForRemoval.forEach(object::remove);
```

Comment: Honestly, there is nothing else that you can do. The original option is pretty valid as well.

Comment: Yeah, it's kind of a shame. Yeah I completely agree. Perfect use case for Iterator.

Comment: No it modifies the underyling JSONObject by removing all keys and effective values if they don't match the key you want to keep which is `a`.

Comment: @HarshalParekh, your original solution works perfectly well, just tested it locally.

Comment: Got it. But, it will need additional space for the entire `JSONObject` to be stored in the `ArrayList`.

Comment: @rxn1d. yes, it is mentioned in the question.

Comment: You asked for elegancy, not efficiency.

Comment: @Jason, fair enough

Comment: None the less I hope this helps.

Comment: @Jason, can the solution be modified for JSONArrays as well? Question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61037130/remove-all-elements-except-one-from-jsonarray-of-jsonobjects

Comment: @rxn1d You can do [something simpler.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61037335/1746118)