# Remove all elements except one from JSONArray of JSONObjects

Tags: java, arrays, json, java-8

I have a JSONArray (org.json) like this:

```
[
    { "a": "a" },
    { "b": "a" },
    { "c": "a" },
    { "d": "a" },
    { "e": "a" },
    { "f": "a" },
    { "g": "a" }
]
```

I would like to remove all the `JSONObject`s that **do not** have the key `a`. Is there a better way to do other than my naive approach?

```
Iterator objects = jsonArray.iterator();
while (objects.hasNext()) {
    Object o = objects.next();
    if (o instanceof JSONObject && !((JSONObject) o).has("a")) {
        objects.remove();
    }
}
```

Expected output:

```
[{"a": "a"}]
```

Comment: JSONArray#remove not working as intended for some reason. Trying to provide a better solution.

Comment: Yeah so the problem is that you can't remove from a JSONArray the object, only the index of the object. If you iterate all of the indices you want to remove, the underlying list is modified on each call so the indices are no longer proper after the first remove call.

Comment: Provided a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're seeking a functional style solution, you can wrap the `Iterator` into a `Stream` and then do whatever you want.

One of the functional solutions:

```
JSONArray newJsonArray =
        StreamSupport.stream(jsonArray.spliterator(), false)
                     .filter(JSONObject.class::isInstance)
                     .map(JSONObject.class::cast)
                     .filter(j -> j.has("a"))
                     .collect(collectingAndThen(toList(), JSONArray::new));
```

**Note**: The solution above does not modify the original `JSONArray`. Following the principles of functional programming one should prefer collecting into a new object rather than modifying the existing one.

Comment: with due change as in `StreamSupport.stream(jsonArray.spliterator()...` since spliterator is a method above `Iterable` and not `Iterator`, this would be clean. (no idea who'd downvoted, but yeah mine balances it out)... also this should mention that it would not modify the underlying array and would need further processing as well.

Comment: to fill in the details in case of comparison, the complete solution here might look like `List<JSONObject> jsonObjects = StreamSupport.stream(jsonArray.spliterator(), false)
                .filter(JSONObject.class::isInstance)
                .map(JSONObject.class::cast)
                .filter(j -> j.has("a"))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        JSONArray jsonArrayNew = new JSONArray(jsonObjects);`

Comment: @Naman Right. Your complete solution looks almost the same as mine. Initially I just pointed OP in the functional direction. Although adding a complete solution makes much more sense. Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid using type casts, try:

```
private static final String JSON = "{\"arr\": [" +
        "{\"z\": \"z\"}," +
        "{\"a\": \"a\"}," +
        "{\"b\": \"b\"}," +
        "{\"c\": \"c\"}" +
        "]}";
. . .
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(JSON);
JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("arr");
JSONArray filtered = new JSONArray();

for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject sub = array.getJSONObject(i);
    if (sub.has("a")) {
         filtered.put(sub);
     }
}

jsonObject.put("arr", filtered);
System.out.println(jsonObject.toString());
```

Result:

```
{"arr":[{"a":"a"}]}
```

Comment: Thanks. This works, but I'd prefer the solution with `StreamSupport` because of elegance.

Answer (score 1):

What we can do is map all JSONObjects to a List if they contain the key `a`. Then we can create a new JSONArray from that List of objects, which in this case is only 1.

You can technically do this in a single line but it looks a bit worse IMO.

```
List<JSONObject> objects = IntStream.range(0, array.length())
        .filter(index -> array.get(index) instanceof JSONObject)
        .mapToObj(array::getJSONObject)
        .filter(object -> object.has("a"))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

JSONArray reduced = new JSONArray(objects);
```

Comment: does `getJSONObject` work for all types of entries in `JSONArray`?

Comment: OP was specifically looking for objects in the JSONArray that were instances of JSONObject.

Comment: from the docs *"@throws JSONException If there is no value for the index or if the value is not JSONObject"* ...while you are performing `getJSONObject` on every index within the array.

Comment: Now one can easily compare how good or bad that `map, filter, map, filter` chain would read.

Comment: Honestly it's actually such a long and messy solution at this point. Perfect example of over engineering.